# How to get size of a structure within the .data section in x86 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

In my X86 Assembly code, I have a structure in the .data section.  How would I get the size of it? Calling `sizeof` doesn't seem to work...

```
myaddr:
         .byte   0,2             # sin_family
         .byte   8,0             # sin_port
         .byte   137,48,187,123  # s_addr
         .byte   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 # fluff
myaddr_end:
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hint: `length=end-start`

Comment: What assembler are you using? Most of them do have a pseudo-operand for this.